# Text Below Baseline Doesn't Change Color on Hover

Tags: css, font-face

I just added a font via @fontface to my main menu with the a:hover property changing the color of the text. It works as it should, but it leaves a portion of the text unchanged (only on hover!).  I've found little on this specific issue. I've tried -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; This is the CSS

```
     @font-face {
        font-family:"UKIJ Diwani Tom";
        src:url("http://al-waheedhalalcanada.com/fonts/arabic-menu/UKIJDiT.eot?") format("eot"),
        url("http://al-waheedhalalcanada.com/fonts/arabic-menu/UKIJDiT.woff") format("woff"),
        url("http://al-waheedhalalcanada.com/fonts/arabic-menu/UKIJDiT.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("http://al-waheedhalalcanada.com/fonts/arabic-menu/UKIJDiT.svg#UKIJDiwaniTom") format("svg");
        font-weight:normal;
        font-style:normal;
        }

.n ul { 
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:940px;
}

.n ul li {
    height:50px;
    display:inline;
    font-size: 18px; 
    font-weight: 400; 
    margin-right: -3px;
    font-family: 'UKIJ Diwani Tom';
    padding:0 8px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='data:image/png;base64,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',sizingMethod=crop);
  zoom: 1;
     }



.n ul li a {  
    line-height: 35px; 
    color: #106333; 
    }

.n ul li.current_page_item a {  
    color: #eef0ee; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    background:url(http://al-waheedhalalcanada.com/images/star.png) left no-repeat;
    padding: 5px 0 0 32px; 
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    }

.n ul li a:hover { 
    color: #eef0ee; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    line-height: 35px;
}
```

Here is a link to the site http://al-waheedhalalcanada.com/build

Comment: This seems like a problem with the font. You could try duplicating the div and placing one underneath the current one you have, then on hover, fading the opacity so the bottom div is revealed in the other color.

Comment: that's an idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for the most part. I added 5px via text-align to the list item. This shifted the text above the baseline. I'm still working on 1 letter ( the A in the About tab ) that needs to be shifted right about 2px. Padding is not the answer.